# jQuery color animate falls to "white"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

There are "gaps" (switching to white color) between "red" and "orange" and between "green" and "lightblue" in both directions.

Can you please explain, why it there?

```
    var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "lightblue", "blue", "purple"];
    var pos = 0;

    switchColor();

function switchColor() {
    $("#sample").animate({color: colors[pos]}, 4000);
    pos++;
    if(colors.length == pos) {
        pos = 0;
        colors.reverse();
    }
    window.setTimeout(function() { switchColor(); }, 1500)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dw1m021y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the call to `animate` doesn't recognise `orange` or `lightblue` because I experience no issues if I replace the values with their hexadecimal equivalents (`#ffa500` for `orange` and `#ADD8E6` for `lightblue`).

It might be a good idea to report the issue using the [jQuery bug tracker](https://bugs.jquery.com/) if the workaround with the hexadecimal values isn't suitable for your needs.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/dw1m021y/2/)

Comment: Many thanks! :) You are right, that is really interesting issue, I'll report.